# Pythonで収集したデータをmongodbに格納したい

Tags: python, python3, mongodb

上記の方のプログラムを動かしたいです。

http://www.inmyzakki.com/entry/2017/05/17/190000

Pythonでtwitterのデータを収集し、MongoDBに格納したいです。

実行すると以下のようにエラーが出ています。

```
File "gettweet.py", line 16
    connect = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

特にエラーがないと思えるのですが、なぜいけないのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

以下がソースコードになります。

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session, OAuth1
import json
import requests
import urllib
import sys
import io
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

def initialize():
    global twitter,connect, db, tweetdata, meta
    twitter = OAuth1Session(KEYS['consumer_key'],KEYS['consumer_secret'],
                            KEYS['access_token'],KEYS['access_secret']

    connect = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = connect.kenko2
    tweetdata= db.tweetdata
    meta= db.metadata2
    posi_nega_dict = db.posinegadict

#検索文字列設定
word = "健康"
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, encoding='utf-8')

#apiキー情報設定
consumer_key = "*********"
consumer_key_secret = "*********"
access_token = "*********"
access_token_secret = "*********"



#twitterAPIアクセス
url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&lang=ja&q=" + word
auth = OAuth1(consumer_key, consumer_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
response = requests.get(url, auth = auth)
data = response.json().get('statuses')


cnt = 0
while True:
    if not data:break
    for tweet in data:
        print("------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print(tweet["id"])#ツイートID
        print(tweet["text"])#ツイート内容
        print(tweet["created_at"])#ツイート日時
        cnt += 1
        maxid = int(tweet["id"]) - 1

    #ツイートがない場合ループ終了
    if len(data) == 0:
        break

    url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&lang=ja&q=" + word + "&max_id=" + str(maxid)
    auth = OAuth1(consumer_key, consumer_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
    response = requests.get(url, auth = auth)
    data = response.json()['statuses']
    print("ツイート数:" + str(cnt))

print(True)
```

Comment: スタックオーバーフローではコードはインデントで表します。エディタの{}ボタンを押すとインデントできます。Syntax Errorは                            `KEYS['access_token'],KEYS['access_secret']}`の最後の}が原因です。Python初心者でしたらPyCharmとかIDEを使うとこの手のエラーは簡単にわかります。

Comment: Kenjiさん2つ続けてありがとうございます。インデントが足りておりませんでした。修正させて頂きました。失礼しました。

Comment: この質問はもう解決されているのでしょうか？

Comment: inasyncさんありがとうございます。解決しております。